# Why EJB timers are being deleted after server shutdown?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer

I'm using Glassfish 4 to deploy EJB beans which are supposed to create persistent EJB timers(TimerConfig) and everything works well as long as the server keeps running without interruption. The problem comes when there's a server shutdown(intentionally I'm shutting it down for testing case) and then get restarted. Once the server gets restarted, the timers which are still waiting for their timeOut to come, get deleted. This doesn't make sense because the timers are being created as persistent but still get removed every time I run the test case explained above. 
Here is part of the log info that comes after restarting the server:

```
Info:   Loading EJBTimerService. Please wait.
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TimerBean: [java:global/ejb-timer-service-app/TimerBean, java:global/ejb-timer-service-app/TimerBean!org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.TimerLocal]
Info:   Loading application [ejb-timer-service-app] at [/ejb-timer-service-app]
Info:   ejb.timer_service_started
Info:   ==> Restoring Timers ... 
Info:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
Info:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Info:   file:/C:/Users/Josimar/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/8.0/config/GF_4.0/domain1/applications/ejb-timer-service-app/WEB-INF/classes/___EJB__Timer__App login successful
Info:   [1] EJB Timers owned by this server will be restored when timeout beans are loaded
Info:   <== ... Timers Restored.
Info:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB SchedulerUtil: [java:global/ApplicationCIB/framework.egov.scheduler/SchedulerUtil, java:global/ApplicationCIB/framework.egov.scheduler/SchedulerUtil!mn.interactive.framework.egov.scheduler.utils.SchedulerUtil]
Warning:   Container org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSContainer@9730004 doesn't support class com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.Module
```

And then information about the timer being deleted:

```
Info:   [1] timers deleted for id: 93015853473529856
Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 93015853473529856
Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 93015853473529856
Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 93015853473529856
Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 93015853473529856
Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 93015853473529856
Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 93015853473529856
Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 93015853473529856
```

So once the corresponding @TimeOut comes up, no action is executed for that timer.

How can I make the timers to survive after a server shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

Check the preferences or settings of your server in your respective IDE and turn the timers  in an increased level.Plus check that your threads are synchronized ,it often creates problem in my experience. 
  Good Luck (Y).